# Littlecms - error during compiling "undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile' "

Tags: c, cs50

Please help me to use LittleCMS framework - I'm receiving 
" undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile' "

I had made:

1) Downloaded from https://github.com/mm2/Little-CMS file lcms2.h

2) Downloaded https://sourceforge.net/projects/lcms/and tried to install it like it written in documentation (downloaded tar file, unTARed it, runned

`./configure
make
sudo make install`

3) Tried to implement a sample from tutorial:

```
#include "lcms2.h"
int main(void)
    {
        cmsHPROFILE hInProfile, hOutProfile;
        cmsHTRANSFORM hTransform;
        hInProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromFile("AdobeRGB1998.icc", "r");
        hOutProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromFile("WebCoatedSWOP2006Grade5.icc", "r");
        hTransform = cmsCreateTransform(hInProfile, TYPE_BGR_8, hOutProfile, TYPE_BGR_8, INTENT_PERCEPTUAL, 0);
        cmsCloseProfile(hInProfile);
        cmsCloseProfile(hOutProfile);
        return 0;
    }
```

After runing "make" I had received " undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile' ".

I think I have to install some library (and I have to add something like this -L/opt/local/lib64 -llcms2 to a makefile or add it to clang ...), but I had read kilobytes of webpages and no one is telling how to do it from scratch - libraries does not appears in folder /opt/local/lib64 or /opt/local/lib (and I cannot find lcms2 in any directory) .

My IDE is: CS50 IDE, Linux version 4.9.17-c9 (root@30db80bfe262) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ).

I am very new in programming, so please, be condescending.
Please help me to solve and to inmplement Little CMS.

Update:
3 types of compilations:

1) Command prompt (internal IDE's makefile, without my Makefile):

```
~/workspace/cmyk/ $ make cmyk
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow   -c -o cmyk.o cmyk.c
clang   cmyk.o  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o cmyk
cmyk.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:9: undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:10: undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
cmyk.o:/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: more undefined references to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds' follow
cmyk.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `cmsCreateTransform'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:14: undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:15: undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cmyk] Error 1
```

2) Makefile1 (with clang):

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
EXE = cmyk
HDRS = lcms2.h
LIBS =
SRCS = cmyk.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile
clean:
    rm -f core $(EXE) *.o
```

Output:

```
~/workspace/cmyk/ $ make cmyk
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror   -c -o cmyk.o cmyk.c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -o cmyk cmyk.o 
cmyk.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:9: undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:10: undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:12: undefined reference to `cmsCreateTransform'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:14: undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:15: undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cmyk] Error 1
```

3) Makefile2:

```
iEdit: cmyk.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ -std=c99
.c.o:
    gcc -c $< -std=c99
cmyk.o:     lcms2.h
```

Output:

```
~/workspace/cmyk/ $ make cmyk
gcc -c cmyk.c -std=c99
clang   cmyk.o  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o cmyk
cmyk.o: In function `main':
cmyk.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
cmyk.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
cmyk.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `cmsCreateTransform'
cmyk.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
cmyk.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cmyk] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: show how you compiled yr sample app

Comment: you need to find the library setup up by the make install you did and refernce it in your linker command

Comment: look for /usr/local/lib......

Comment: 3 types of make:
1) Via command prompt (clang): 
`clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    projectName.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o projectName`

Comment: 2) `
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror
EXE = cmyk
# space-separated list of header files
HDRS = lcms2.h
# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS =
# space-separated list of source files
SRCS = cmyk.c
# automatically generated list of object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# default target
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
# dependencies 
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile
# housekeeping
clean:
 rm -f core $(EXE) *.o
`

Comment: Output:
`~/workspace/cmyk/ $ make cmyk -f Makefile
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror   -c -o cmyk.o cmyk.c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -o cmyk cmyk.o 
cmyk.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:9: undefined reference to `cmsOpenProfileFromFile'
...
/home/ubuntu/workspace/cmyk/cmyk.c:15: undefined reference to `cmsCloseProfile'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cmyk] Error 1`

Comment: 3) Makefile2 (gcc):
`iEdit: projectName.o  
  gcc $^ -o $@ -std=c99
    .c.o:
  gcc -c $< -std=c99
    projectName.o:     lcms2.h`

Comment: @pm100 this folder does not include my libs: `/usr/local/lib/ $ ls
python2.7/  python3.4/  site_ruby/`

Comment: you need to include -llcms2 in your build. YOu just need to find where make install put it. Seems that it uses pkgconfig , read up on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use other IDE - CS50 IDE does not allowed to install additional libraries. I had installed VirtualBox, mounted xubuntu, installed lib, added `-L/usr/local/lib -llcms2` to Makefile and my program was compiled without errors.